# Run Job Once every time JobConstraints are met

Tags: android

I m using JobService as made compulsory by Android 8 instead of using Action_Power_Connected receiver now to run my job. Below is the code

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher jobDispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
  Builder ldsjobspecial = jobDispatcher.newJobBuilder();
        ldsjobspecial.setService(LDSJobServiceLimited.class)
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                .setRecurring(false).setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK, Constraint.DEVICE_CHARGING)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(100, 120))
                .setReplaceCurrent(true)
                .setTag("jobtag");

 jobDispatcher.mustSchedule(ldsjobspecial.build());
```

if I use setRecurring false, job runs only once I set it and it never runs on next time when device is put on charging. In case I use setRecurring true, Job keep running at defined interval throughout charging.

Pls suggest how to achieve. Earlier I was using receiver which was calling job on power connected and once power is disconnected it does not run.

Comment: Create a broadcastReceiver to receive `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` event and schedule a job there.

Comment: I was using that only so far, but in Android 8, u can not use it now.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html